# Phonegap + backbone.js

Tags: cordova, backbone.js

So I am building a phonegap application which sends getJson requests and receives some data to display. However the requests are a little bit slow. My question is , if I used any js framework like backbone, would it make my app run faster?
Currently I don't use anything but javascript and jquery library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backbone is usually used with jQuery, so no, it would not make your app faster. Using additional libraries and frameworks is almost never going to make your code faster, instead you should try to find out what takes so long and optimize that.